# Node installation: No module named gyp.common

Tags: centos, node.js

I was trying to install node.js on CentOS 6.4 VirtualBox guest on a Windows XP host with the following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/src/
git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
make install
```

I only reached as far as `./configure`. When I executed `./configure` I got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./configure", line 14, in
<module> from gyp.common import GetFlavor
ImportError: No module named gyp.common
```

Comment: +1 `whereis python` returns `python: /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz`

Answer (score 3):

what version of python do you have it installed. check `python -V`

before you run `./configure`, make sure you have the following prerequisites completed.

```
* GCC 4.2 or newer
* Python 2.6 or 2.7
* GNU Make 3.81 or newer
* libexecinfo (FreeBSD and OpenBSD only)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. `python -V` returns `Python 2.6.6`. I have `gcc version 4.4.7` installed  I have `GNU Make 3.81`

Comment: However, I do not have libexecinfo installed. `which libexecinfo` displayed `usr/bin/which: no libexecinfo in (/usr/local/:...)`

Answer (score 1):

The `./configure` calls Python, which you already do have installed (the Traceback message is from a working Python).

I just did a fresh git checkout of and it configures with both python 2.6 and 2.7.

What `./configure` is failing to find is  [Generate Your Progject](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/), which should be included in the tools/gyp directory. 
If those files are not there, git might have missed a beat.

This can also be caused by a different `gyp` module, than the one provided in node.js, being found by python. To check that you can do

```
$ python
>>> import gyp
>>> print gyp.__file__
```

if you don't get an 'ImportError' this shows you which file Python actually imports.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is either wrong with your clone copy of `node.js` or something is up with the mix of packages you have installed on your CentOS 6.4 box. I have that same distro here and I just did the same steps you did and it worked.

```
$ ./configure
{ 'target_defaults': { 'cflags': [],
                       'default_configuration': 'Release',
                       'defines': [],
                       'include_dirs': [],
                       'libraries': []},
  'variables': { 'clang': 0,
                 'gcc_version': 44,
                 'host_arch': 'x64',
                 'node_install_npm': 'true',
                 'node_prefix': '',
                 'node_shared_cares': 'false',
                 'node_shared_http_parser': 'false',
                 'node_shared_libuv': 'false',
                 'node_shared_openssl': 'false',
                 'node_shared_v8': 'false',
                 'node_shared_zlib': 'false',
                 'node_tag': '',
                 'node_unsafe_optimizations': 0,
                 'node_use_dtrace': 'false',
                 'node_use_etw': 'false',
                 'node_use_openssl': 'true',
                 'node_use_perfctr': 'false',
                 'node_use_systemtap': 'false',
                 'python': '/usr/bin/python',
                 'target_arch': 'x64',
                 'v8_enable_gdbjit': 0,
                 'v8_no_strict_aliasing': 1,
                 'v8_use_snapshot': 'true'}}
creating  ./config.gypi
creating  ./config.mk
```

As @Anthon suggested I ran the following commands and I don't even have the `gyp.common` Python package installed either when I ran the above `./configure` command, and yet it worked fine.

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 22 2013, 00:00:18) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gyp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gyp
```

So I'm not really sure what's going on with your environment. I would debug it a little bit further and take a look at your `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables to determine if you're getting the version of Python that you think you are.

#### workaround

If you don't require the latest `node.js` you can just install it from the yum repositories for CentOS 6.4. Most of the Node.js toolset is already pre-built for you in the EPEL repository, which you should have by default. So just run this command to install it:

```
$ sudo yum install nodejs
```

All the other packages are available if you do search for `nodejs`.

```
$ yum search nodejs
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.liquidweb.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
 * updates: centos.mbni.med.umich.edu
73 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
======================================================= N/S Matched: nodejs ========================================================
nodejs-burrito.noarch : Wrap up expressions with a trace function while walking the AST
nodejs-delayed-stream.noarch : Buffers events from a stream until you are ready to handle them
nodejs-npm-registry-client.noarch : Client for the npm registry
nodejs-options.noarch : Light-weight in-code option parser for nodejs
nodejs-osenv.noarch : Look up environment settings specific to different operating systems
...
...
```

Comment: It is actually good that your `import gyp` does throw an error. I have a suspicion that the OP has some gyp in his Python package search path that gets included before the one in the node.js source tree.

Comment: @Anthon - that's what I suspected as well. You're more versed in Python than I, so I didn't want to jump to a conclusion.